# How do you interpret this code correctly step by step? (New to programming)

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

My problem is that I dont know how the compiler runs through the different if statements correctly and why he skips some in this case.

I tried checking  if the conditions from start to bottom are true or false and thus find the correct output of the program. But why doesnt the program output 84 here:

```
if (a > c) cout << 84;
else cout << 48
```

Full Program:

```
int main()
{
  constexpr int a{8};
  constexpr int b{4};
  constexpr int c{1};

  if (a < b < c)
    if (c > b > a)
      if (a > c) cout << 84;
      else cout << 48;
    else
      if (b < c) cout << 14;
      else cout << 41;
  else
    if (b < a < c)
      if (a < c) cout << 81;
      else cout << 18;
    else
      if (b < c) cout << 17;
      else cout << 71;

  return 0;
}
```

The program outputs only 41. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is a nonsense:

```cpp
if (a < b < c)
```

It will be evaluated as:

```cpp
if (a < bool(b < c))
```

The lt/gt/eq/ne/le/ge operators are binary - i.e. they require two arguments. You should be doing something like:

```cpp
if (a < b && b < c)
```

Comment: It is wrong as it should be  if if (bool(a <b) < c) which will go to if(0<c) as evaluated true as < are left-associative . If your statement is right then it will be evaluated false. but it is true as your statement reduces to if(a<0)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are a newbie. Don't skip braces. Now Let's go through it step by step 
In your first if-else. Here your a=8 , b= 4 , c=1. This is how your code is proceeding

```
if (a < b< c)  // equivalent to if(0<c) due to left associativity// firstly a<b will be evaluated which 0 and hence statement  is true as c is 1.
{
if (c > b > a) // equiavelnt to if(bool(c>b)>a) which is false as c>b is 0 hence it will reduce to if(0>c) .execution goes to else block.
{

    if (a > c)
    {
       cout << 84;
    }
    else
    {
       cout << 48;
    }
}
else
{
    if (b < c) // it is false. execution goes to else 
    {
        cout << 14;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << 41; // it is printed.
    }
}
```

}